# Dual Boot Ubuntu Various Questions

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, hard-drive, dell, laptop

If I dual boot Ubuntu alongside windows 10 with a bootable usb drive will it install Ubuntu on the usb drive or on my internal hard drive?

After installation of Ubuntu, do I need to plug in my bootable usb drive  to run Ubuntu again?

I have two usb drives with the Ubuntu iso setup on them with Rufus. However, after testing each, only one of them shows up in my Bios boot options. Why is this?

After following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSVV_EoApdo I setup my 8gb Sandisk Usb drive with the Ubuntu iso on it using Rufus. However, after booting to ubuntu from my bios and proceeding with the installation, it tells me that Ubuntu does not have enough space to install. So does this mean Ubuntu was trying to install on my usb drive or on my internal hard drive?

Edit: Here is what I am getting on my screen when I am installing in order.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6V04s.jpg

Final Edit and Solution: So my ssd as in my bios is configured as RAID for my windows 10 setup. In order for Ubuntu to detect my hard drive I have to switch it to AHCI. So after switching my hard drive to AHCI in my bios and then booting up ubuntu install from the usb, I am finally able to complete the Ubuntu install. However, I still have to switch the hard drive bios setting each time I switch OS which is not the most convenient.

I am using a Dell XPS 9575 Laptop which could be a reason for this.

So far I am enjoying Ubuntu A LOT. Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: @karel I followed the tutorial I linked above. I have tried legacy boot. That thread does not answer my questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764)

Comment: That other post addresses part of the question.  He has a few additional questions, which I addressed in an answer.

Comment: If installing beside Win 10(you want to keep 10) need to be careful during install.  Watch what you are doing.  After installation do not need USB drive, nice to keep handy.  For the none booting USB drive could be a bad burn, bad drive or a few other problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Ubunuto will install on the internal hard drive.  You can specify where you want it installed.  You can't install Ubunto onto the Live Ubunto USB.  It's telling you there is no space because it doesn't see a place to install.

Go into Windows, Start, type diskmgmt.msc in the search box, and reduce the size of the Windows partition, to make room for Ubuntu.  Leave the space as unallocated.  Reboot with the Ubunto iso.  Install it to that unallocated space.

If you want to install Ubunto onto that 8GB Sandisk card (not an iso version, but a version where you can save files and add apps - an iso is an unchangeable image), you need to either have another Sandisk to boot from, or you can run install from the Ubunto you installed to your hard drive.

If Ubuntu is installed on your internal disk, when you boot up it will ask you which OS you want to run.

If you install Ubuntu on the Sandisk instead, you have the option of having Ubunto put Grub (the OS selector) on the internal drive, or not.  The first option is straightforward.  The easiest way to accomplish the second option is to disable the internal drive in BIOS, or physically take it out, and then run the Ubuntu install ISO (you need an extra booting Sandisk to do this).  This latter option leave your internal hard drive alone.  It won't put Grub on there.

Comment: I have a partition for Ubuntu. It doesn't ask where to install Ubuntu. After choosing install Ubuntu in GRUB it leads me to choose my language and such and then says it needs (I don't know the specifics) 8.2 gb while my usb drive is 8gb. Then I have to hit cancel.

Comment: Choose "do something else" at the bottom of the install menu.

Comment: That's not an option. @JasonF4

Comment: I'll take a picture of what's on my screen and put the link here.

Comment: Okay, the current version of Ubuntu won't install on an 8GB drive.  You could install Linx Mint Xfce on that Sandisk.  It's based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and it is a lot lighter weight.

Comment: Check my edits.

Comment: Does that mean that it is only installing it for the setup or is it putting the OS on the usb drive?

Comment: Your screencap shows that Ubuntu checked the computer, and there isn't at least 8.6GB available.  Boot into Windows, click the WIndows icon (bottom left) type diskmgmt.msc in the search box, and see if there's space available to shrink the Windows partition (you can shrink it there).  You could post a screen-grab of the Window.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qmN5ba8

Comment: Okay, that's plenty of space.  Was that Unallocated partition already there, or did you just create it?  If you just created it, proceed with the Ubuntu installation.  --  And no, you won't need that Sandisk in the USB port to boot into Ubunto after its installed.

Comment: If the install still won't proceed, you can try disabling fast-boot in the BIOS.   (You press a key during boot to get there - the instruction are computer-specific.)  It's possible there's a glitch, and it's making the non-NTFS partition looking like it's locked.

Comment: It was already there. I'll try disabling fast boot.

Comment: I got ubuntu working but it was an issue with how my ssd is used on my laptop. Check my edits for more detail.